# Iterate and link across elements in XML source with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Two questions:

1. How to link each  from the first  with the corresponding  from the other  based on their perfectly matching ids? Example of XML source:

   > <DIV>
   >
   > > <div id="fr">
   > >
   > > > <seg id="fr_1">abc</seg>
   > > >       <seg id="fr_2">def</seg>
   > > >       <seg id="fr_3">ghi</seg> 
   > > >       <seg id="fr_4">jkl</seg> 
   > > >       <seg id="fr_5">mno</seg> 
   > > >       </div> 
   > > >       <div id="en"> 
   > > >       <seg id="en_1">AAA</seg> 
   > > >       <seg id="en_2">BBB</seg> 
   > > >       <seg id="en_3">CCC</seg> 
   > > >       <seg id="en_4">DDD</seg> 
   > > >       <seg id="en_5">EEE</seg> 
   > > >       </div> 
   > > >       </DIV>
2. How to link segs from across two or more divs based on linking established with @corresp? Example of XML source:

   > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   >
   > > <DIV>
   > >
   > > > <div id="fr">
   > > >
   > > > > <seg id="fr_1" corresp="#en_1">abc</seg>
   > > > >         <seg id="fr_2" corresp="#en_2 #en3">def</seg>
   > > > >         <seg id="fr_3" corresp="#en_3 #en_4">ghi</seg>
   > > > >         <seg id="fr_4" corresp="#en_4 #en_5">jkl</seg>
   > > > >         <seg id="fr_5" corresp="#en_6">mno</seg>
   > > > >         </div>
   > > > >         <div id="en">
   > > > >         <seg id="en_1" corresp="#fr_1">ab</seg>
   > > > >         <seg id="en_2" corresp="#fr_1 #fr_2">cde</seg>
   > > > >         <seg id="en_3" corresp="#fr_2 #fr_3">fg</seg>
   > > > >         <seg id="en_4" corresp="#fr_3 fr_4">hij</seg>
   > > > >         <seg id="en_5" corresp="#fr_4">kl</seg>
   > > > >         <seg id="en_6" corresp="#fr_5">mno</seg>
   > > > >         </div>
   > > > >         </DIV>

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean by "link segs"? Do you have a specific example of what you want to do with this input?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @JLRishe The HTML output for the first task should look as this:
>1.abc AAA
>2.def BBB
>3. ghi CCC
>4. jkl DDD
>5. mno EEE

The HTML output for the other task is to look as this:
>1. abc ab
>2. abc cde
>3.def cde
>4. def fg
>5. Ghi fg
>6. Ghi hij
>7.jkl hij
>8. jkl kl
>9.mno mno

Comment: @gabrielemucho, consider to ask a second question for the second problem.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, for the first solution, nicely done, works well. The second question concerns the 2nd XML source, which is more complicate. The values of <seg> elements should be grouped by using the attributes @corresp, which show how <seg> values relate to each other. The desired output should look as follows: >1. abc ab >2. abc cde >3.def cde >4. def fg >5. Ghi fg >6. Ghi hij >7.jkl hij >8. jkl kl >9.mno mno (commas are not desired to separate the strings in the output). Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a grouping problem, with XSLT 1.0 you solve it using Muenchian grouping http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml; that way the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="id" match="seg" use="substring-after(@id, '_')"/>

<xsl:template match="DIV">
  <xsl:copy>
    <ol>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="div/seg[generate-id() = generate-id(key('id', substring-after(@id, '_'))[1])]"/>
    </ol>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="seg">
  <li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('id', substring-after(@id, '_'))" mode="list"/>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="seg" mode="list">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms the input

```
<DIV>

    <div id="fr">

        <seg id="fr_1">abc</seg>
        <seg id="fr_2">def</seg>
        <seg id="fr_3">ghi</seg>
        <seg id="fr_4">jkl</seg>
        <seg id="fr_5">mno</seg>
        </div>
        <div id="en">
        <seg id="en_1">AAA</seg>
        <seg id="en_2">BBB</seg>
        <seg id="en_3">CCC</seg>
        <seg id="en_4">DDD</seg>
        <seg id="en_5">EEE</seg>
        </div>
        </DIV>
```

into the output

```
<DIV>
   <ol>
      <li>abc, AAA</li>
      <li>def, BBB</li>
      <li>ghi, CCC</li>
      <li>jkl, DDD</li>
      <li>mno, EEE</li>
   </ol>
</DIV>
```